# What changes are required to run spring boot project in browser as localhost?

Tags: postgresql, maven, spring-boot, jpa

When I run the command for spring boot project:

> mvn spring-boot:run

The code shows build success message, and it ends.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.084 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-03T11:28:11+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 64M/899M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But I want to display the working code on browser on http://localhost:8080. 
Application stops immediately instead of starting a web server, the project ends.
Does the code need any changes to run on localhost?

Here is my OMSApplication.java class

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableEnvironmentJKS
public class OMSApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(OMSApplication.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(
                OMSApplication.class, args);
        log.info(" Application context created: {}" , applicationContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(OMSApplication.class);
    }

}
```

And here is pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.mpms.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>oms-services</artifactId>
    <!-- <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>oms-services</name>
    <description>oms services</description>

    <parent>
       <groupId>com.example.mpms</groupId>
       <artifactId>mpms-oms</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <configuration>    
                <skip>true</skip> 
                <!-- <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <APIE_PLATFORM>DEV</APIE_PLATFORM>
                    <APIE_REGION>US</APIE_REGION>
                    <APIE_ZONE>STL</APIE_ZONE>
                </systemPropertyVariables> -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions> 
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>${mvn-site-plugin-version}</version>
       </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

I have not included all the dependencies here, as they are many.

And here is the controller class:

```
@RestController
public class OrderController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderController.class); 

    @Autowired
    private KYCOrderService kycOrderService;

    /**
     * Health check URL for application via synapse.
     * 
     * */
    @GetMapping(value = "/health",produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> healthCheck() {
        String output = String.format("Heartbeat :%s", "Cumulus- Order Management Service: I'm healthy!");
        LOGGER.info(output);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(output,HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @PostMapping(path="/oms/order/kyc", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @ApiOperation(value = "Place an Offline KYC Order", notes = "Order is placed in central oms", response = OfflineKYCOrderResponse.class, tags={ "OfflineKYCOrderResponse", })
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OfflineKYCOrderResponse creation OK", response = OfflineKYCOrderResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Created", response = OfflineKYCOrderResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request", response = OfflineKYCOrderResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized", response = OfflineKYCOrderResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden", response = OfflineKYCOrderResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found", response = OfflineKYCOrderResponse.class)
    })
    public OfflineKYCOrderResponse placeOfflineKycOrder(@ApiParam(value = "Details of order to be placed" ,required=true)@RequestBody OfflineKYCOrderRequest offlineKYCOrder) {
        LOGGER.info("OfflineKYCOrderRequest: {}" , offlineKYCOrder);
        OfflineKYCOrderResponse errorResponse = offlineKYCOrder.validateInput();
        if (null != errorResponse) {
            LOGGER.info("OfflineKYCOrderResponse: {}" , errorResponse);
            return errorResponse;
        }
        ReasonCodes processStatusCode = ReasonCodes.OMS000;
        OfflineKYCOrderResponse offlineKYCOrderResponse = new OfflineKYCOrderResponse();
        try {
            KYCOrder createdKYCOrder = kycOrderService.saveOrder(new KYCOrder(offlineKYCOrder));
            offlineKYCOrderResponse.setOrderNumber(createdKYCOrder.getOrder().getOrderId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            processStatusCode = ReasonCodes.OMS001;
            LOGGER.error("Failed to store order.", e);
        } finally {
            offlineKYCOrderResponse.setReasonCode(processStatusCode.toString());
            offlineKYCOrderResponse.setReasonDescription(processStatusCode.getDescription());
        }
        LOGGER.info("OfflineKYCOrderResponse: {}" , offlineKYCOrderResponse);
        return offlineKYCOrderResponse;
    }


}
```

Can anyone help solving the problem?

Comment: *Can anyone help solving the problem?*: which problem? You haven't said. What did you do, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead. Remember: we can't see your screen.

Comment: @JBNizet I have written the problem at the starting of the question.

Comment: So the problem is that your application stops immediately, instead of starting a web server and running until you end it? Is that what the problem is? If so, do you have web dependencies in your app? Do you have a controller defined somewhere?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, exactly.  I have all the dependencies including web, jpa, tomcat,etc. I have updated the question by adding controller class.

Comment: Why are you skipping the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`? Also please add the log output for your application to your question, that will have information on what failed.

Comment: Then look at the logs. They should explain what's going on and why the application stops.

Comment: I am getting such type of error in log: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Variable references non-existent resource : ${project_loc:MavenDemo1}

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the spring boot starter package in your pom.xml,
remove the parent dependency from the pom.xml file and replace it with the below depedency

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Alternatively you can use the war from the target folder and deploy it using tomcat or any server of your choice.